# not finding the route - laravel android authentication

Tags: android, laravel

I'm new to laravel and it's just so much confusing for me.
I'm trying to authenticate to it from my android application using `HttpURLConnection` and passing the url i.e http://192.168.1.1:8000/api/login and the headers required for the api.

***my asynctask class:***

```
private String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.1:8000/api/login";
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            String Username = strings[0];
            String Password = strings[1];
            JSONInput = new JSONObject();

            try {

                JSONInput.put("email",Username);
                JSONInput.put("password",Password);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            URL myUri = new URL(LOGIN_URL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUri.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("email",Username);
            connection.setRequestProperty("password",Password);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;
            String result = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                result += line;

            inputStream.close();
            try {
                return JSONInput = new JSONObject(result);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return JSONInput;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return JSONInput;
}
```

***api.php*** in laravel's routes directory:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');

    Route::group([
      'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    });
});
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

1:

Am I passing the wrong url? because it's telling me that the file doesn't exists. I would much appreciate it if you could tell me what I should pass in the url.

2:

I'm passing the headers from `HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty`. is it the proper way?

3:

should I even work the the route or something else?

laravel version is 7.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: I was passing the wrong url and changed it to `http://192.168.1.1:8000/api/auth/login`

2: I used `Retrofit` instead and passed query parameters instead of headers.

3: I was supposed to work with the routes and that was the correct way.